# Change links on page but not in a certain div

Tags: jquery, html, replace, hyperlink

I have written a piece of code that changes the URL of links on my site (this was to fix a bug that had appeared on my site with links when I moved it). However, I now need this code to apply to everything on my site EXCEPT links in one div (#main_designs)

Here is my code:

```
 $('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/kateguestdesigns.com\/about/gi,'kateguestdesigns.com/home/about') );
```

How can I get this to apply to everything EXCEPT the div called #main_designs?

Comment: This is a dangerous operation as it rewrites the entire dom - removes all the registered event handlers and widgets/plugins

Comment: if you can share how is the anchor elements in the page we might be able to  help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return !(a.indexOf(i) > -1);});
};

var yourAnchorTags = $('a').diff($('div#main_designs a')
```

I got the diff function from here: [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)